# Run OpenDJ Cluster on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, opendj

I would like to run an **OpenDJ cluster** in my *kubernetes cluster*. In order to do so I used this [procedure](https://github.com/OpenIdentityPlatform/OpenDJ/wiki/How-To-Run-OpenDJ-in-Kubernetes)

I've created a *StetefulSet*, *service* and *storageclass*.
In order to initialize the replication, I need to run several commands `dsreplication enable and dsreplication initialize-all` inside one of the **StatefulSet** replicas because when I try running those commands through a *kubernetes* job as a separated pod it sends the following error - `The local instance is not configured or you do not have permissions to access it` as the server has not initialized as one of the **opendj cluster**'s replicas (Which has the initial command that launch the **opendj** server).

How would you run those commands from the *statefulsets* pods? (When I keep thinking about scaling - how will I join new pods to the cluster when they'll launch with the *hpa*?)

Or maybe the better question is how can I run commands on my cluster from a remote pod?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that this version of OpenDJ and the deployment referenced in the documentation supports replication. The service doesn't even have any port for replication.

Comment: i've already tried this, total mess, avoid placing your opendj in a pod, use classic vm, if you want to use the paid version, they added support for cloud based infrastrucure, check this release note: <https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/ds/7/release-notes/>